# How do I get the sender IP address from a packet in a PCAP file?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp, pcap

I am most likely missing something here, but the [PCAP specification](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) does not show the sender **IP** address and **PORT** of the packet captured.

Is there a way that I can know who sent the packet in the **PCAP** file?

http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per what EJP said, you will have to parse the packet data yourself.  See [the tcpdump.org link-layer header type page](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) for a list of the values for the `network` field in the file header and the corresponding format of the headers at the beginning of the packet data.

You need to look at those headers to determine whether the packet is an IP packet; if it is, then you need to parse the IPv4 or IPv6 header (depending on whether the headers indicate that it's an IPv4 or IPv6 packet, or, alternatively, on whether the "version" field in the header is 4 or 6 - the "version" field appears in the same location in the IPv4 and IPv6 header; for `LINKTYPE_RAW`, you would have to look at the "version" field, as there are no headers in front of the IPv4 or IPv6 header) to find the source IP address.  See [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) for the form of the IPv4 header; see [RFC 2460](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460) for the form of the IPv6 header.

If you want port numbers, you will have to check the "Protocol" field of the IPv4 header, or check the "Next header" field of the IPv6 header *and* handle extension headers, to determine what protocol is being carried on top of IP.  See the [IANA Protocol Numbers registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xml) for the values of that field; TCP is 6 and UDP is 17.  If the protocol is TCP, see [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) for the format of the TCP header; if the protocol is UDP, see [RFC 768](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768) for the format of the UDP header.

Or you might want to use an existing packet parsing library, such as [libtrace](http://research.wand.net.nz/software/libtrace.php) for C or C++ or other libraries for other languages (I think they may exist for Perl, Python, C#, and Java, for example), as that may let you avoid doing a lot of the above.

(For that matter, you shouldn't need to be looking at the pcap format specification; you should be using libpcap/WinPcap to read the pcap file, as that also means your program may be able to read some pcap-ng files as well, if it's using a sufficiently recent version of libpcap.)

Answer (score 1):

The packet origin is in the IP packet itself. So it doesn't need to be in the PCap headers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the IP address and port numbers of both source and destination endpoints using the below Github example:

https://github.com/arisath/Pcap-dissection/blob/master/PcapDissector.java